# Laravel :: cannot view saved image in public path

Tags: laravel, image, path, public-folders

I have Laravel website saving images viya controller, I uploaded the project on server host, in public_html folder I put public folder files.
other folders and files put on folder outside public_html

```
/home/domain_user
public_html
|__ images
project_folder
|__app
|__bootstrap
|__ public
    |__images
```

when I save Images it saved in project_folder->public->images
and when i used assets to view images it use images in  :public_html->images

save image code :

```
$image_name=$post->id.'_'.$image_counter.'.jpg';
$image->move(public_path().'/images/posts/', $image_name);
```

view image code :

```
$image='images/posts/'.$post->id.'_1.jpg';
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset($image) }}" alt="Third slide">
```

How can I save and vuew image to and from same path?

Comment: Have you tried manually setting path to image tag <img src='http://some_url/public/images/{imageId}' />

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the public folder direction. (default is on laravel/public)

add this code to bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->usePublicPath(realpath(__DIR__.'/../../public_html'));
```

If not works, use second way:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return realpath(__DIR__.'/../../public_html');
});
```

Anyway, it is better to use Storage so that you don't have these problems.

Comment: this make the website dont opened

Comment: @SarmedMQBerwari What is your Laravel version?

Comment: @SarmedMQBerwari I added a new way. check this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it :

```
$image_name=$post->id.'_'.$image_counter.'.jpg';
$image->move('/images/posts/', $image_name);  // just remove : public_path().
```